# Laravel 8 @push to @stack makes script not working as expected

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to call a js file from a blade template, so I have a main blade template with: `@stack('custom-scripts')`

Then, in a child template, I push a js file with
`@push('custom-scripts')`

The script makes a bootstrap accordion change his icon.

- If the script is inside `<script>` tag written directly in the blade
  template it works.
- If the script is called by  is not working the event `$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse'...`

**Not Working** example:

```
@push('custom-scripts')
        //This line calls the script below, but the event on show.bs.collapse will not fire
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/accordion-details.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

```
//accordion-details.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapse.show").each(function(){
        $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").addClass("fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus");
    });

    //THIS IS NOT FIRING
    $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
        console.log('open collapse');
        $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
    }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
        console.log('hide collapse');
        $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
    });
});
```

**Working** example:

```
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".collapse.show").each(function(){

                $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").addClass("fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus");
            });

            //FIRING AND WORKING AS EXPECTED
            $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
                console.log('open collapse');
                $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
            }).on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
                console.log('hide collapse');
                $(this).prev(".card-header").find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: make sure its after `jquery.js` in the master layout

Comment: Of course, jquery.js is included inside app.js in the header. This script is at the bottom of the body.